# How to add coupon printer?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, cms, functions

Im building a directory site and for each business listing I wanted to include a printable coupon.

I would want users to be able to click the coupon image (or link) and a printable version of the coupon to show up.

I looked around for solutions but couldn't find anything that could help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you explained a little more about what you want to do and how you want to do it.  I have no idea what a "coupon printer" is or how you'd expect it to work.

Comment: Sorry about that...Im building a directory site and for each business listing I wanted to include a printable coupon. I would want users to be able to click the coupon image (or link) and a printable version of the coupon to show up. I thought this would be more obvious to me, but apparently not. Not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be probably looking for a plugin that offer's groupon-like functionality ([“Groupon 1.0 started on a WordPress blog.”](http://www.tomloverro.com/2010/08/19/groupon-1-0-started-on-a-wordpress-blog/)).

By googling I learned that there is a plugin called [WP Coupon (Wordpress Plugin)](http://www.wpcoupon.com/) ([review](http://www.wpnow.com/wp-coupon-review)). No idea if it fits in what you need, but it looks like it does what you're looking for.

But it's probably additionally worth to checkout if groupon and other similar fast growing sites do offer a webservice so that actually the job is already done:

- [Groupon API](http://www.groupon.com/pages/api-terms-of-use)

Comment: Thanks, Im using the CouponPress theme for wordpress. In general, it does mostly what I need. I just have to make some customiztions.

Answer (score 0):

First figure out how you want your coupons displayed.

For simple printouts you can apply a css style-sheet for a printer friendly version, but I'm assuming you want a better coupon maybe with an actual bar code in it. In that case you want to have a pdf printer friendly coupon, since it the most popular format for printing these types of things.

There are several pdf plugins for WordPress that either turn a post into a pdf/embed a pdf into your page or simpley link to a pdf version of your coupon to download.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://lesterchan.net/wordpress/readme/wp-print.html) plugin in a similar situation. It auto generats a printable version of your content and add a click-to-print link to it.

Comment: I would prefer using an updated plugin that is compatible with the most recent wordpress release. The new theme that Im using (CouponPress) has that feature built in. Thanks for the feedback.